# find a specific item from a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
portfolio= [ 
( "Purchase Date:23-Aug-2015", "Purchase Price:43.50", "Shares:25",      'Symbol:CAT', "Current Price:92.45" ), 
( "Purchase Date:15-Mar-2013", "Purchase Price:42.80", "Shares:50",     'Symbol:DD', "Current Price:51.19" ), 
( "Purchase Date:7-Dec-2014", "Purchase Price:42.10", "Shares:75", 'Symbol:EK', "Current Price:34.87" ), 
( "Purchase Date:6-Dec-2013", "Purchase Price:37.58", "Shares:100", 'Symbol:GM', "Current Price:37.58" ) 
] 

# loop to iterate over each item in list and print each item out
for a in portfolio:
    print (a[0:5])
```

This is my code and I want to print out a specific item from a tuple, how do I do this?

I want to print out `Purchase price` from `7-Dec-2014`.

Comment: You're using the wrong data structure. You should use a dictionary for this task.

Answer (score 4):

You'd probably be better off putting your data into dictionaries, to do cleaner look ups.

```
portfolio = [
{"Purchase Date":"23-Aug-2015", "Purchase Price":43.50, "Shares":25, "Symbol":"CAT", "Current Price":92.45},
{"Purchase Date":"15-Mar-2013", "Purchase Price":42.80, "Shares":50, "Symbol":"DD", "Current Price":51.19},
{"Purchase Date":"7-Dec-2014", "Purchase Price":42.10, "Shares":75, "Symbol":"EK", "Current Price":34.87},
{"Purchase Date":"6-Dec-2013", "Purchase Price":37.58, "Shares":100, "Symbol":"GM", "Current Price":37.58}
]

for data in portfolio:
    if data["Purchase Date"] == "7-Dec-2014":
        print(data["Purchase Price"])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the first item in the tuple is `"Purchase Date:7-Dec-2014"`. If it is, you can print the second item in the tuple. Here's how to do that:

```
portfolio= [
( "Purchase Date:23-Aug-2015", "Purchase Price:43.50", "Shares:25",      'Symbol:CAT', "Current Price:92.45" ),
( "Purchase Date:15-Mar-2013", "Purchase Price:42.80", "Shares:50",     'Symbol:DD', "Current Price:51.19" ),
( "Purchase Date:7-Dec-2014", "Purchase Price:42.10", "Shares:75", 'Symbol:EK', "Current Price:34.87" ),
( "Purchase Date:6-Dec-2013", "Purchase Price:37.58", "Shares:100", 'Symbol:GM', "Current Price:37.58" )
]

for transaction in portfolio:
    if transaction[0] == "Purchase Date:7-Dec-2014":
        print(transaction[1])
```

This code is quite clunky and is neither Pythonic nor pretty. A more natural way to represent these data is with a dictionary or, more specifically, a dictionary of dictionaries. I'll use transaction dates as the key to transaction data corresponding to that date.

```
transactions = {
  '23-Aug-2015' : { 'Purchase Price' : 43.50, 'Shares' : 25, 'Symbol' : 'CAT', 'Current Price': 92.45 },
  '15-Mar-2013' : { 'Purchase Price' : 42.80, 'Shares' : 50, 'Symbol' : 'DD', 'Current Price': 51.19 },
  '7-Dec-2014' : { 'Purchase Price' : 42.10, 'Shares' : 75, 'Symbol' : 'EK', 'Current Price': 34.87 },
  '6-Dec-2013' : { 'Purchase Price' : 37.58, 'Shares' : 100, 'Symbol' : 'GM', 'Current Price': 37.58 }
}
```

Here's how you can achieve in same goal using a dictionary:

```
# For every key and value pair in transactions
for k, v in transactions.iteritems():
  # If we find a key with December 7th, 2014 as the date
  if k == '7-Dec-2014':
    # Print the purchase price of the transaction from that date.
    print v['Purchase Price']
```

This allows you to access data without needing to do any special parsing of strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through `portfolio` and check if the Purchase date you're looking for is in any of the tuples. If so, you can print it provided the Purchase price is always in the same position in all of the tuples.

```
for i in portfolio:
    if "Purchase Date:7-Dec-2014" in i:
        print (i[1])
```

Comment: Using `in` to check the first element of a tuple is inefficient and `i` is a quite bad name for a loop variable which isn't an integer value.

Comment: @BlackJack Thanks for your comment. There are many opinions on  why `i` is often used to name a loop variable. My understanding is that `i`, `j` and `k` are usually used for iterative variables. As far as membership testing, I believe it's pretty much the same in tuples and lists.

Comment: `i`, `j`, and `k` are often used for subscripts in mathematics and are almost always ∊ℕ and that's how they came into use as loop variables used as index into arrays. Having such a name for something more complex is a nasty surprise for the reader. Apart from that it's also a terrible name for something in a portfolio as it has no meaning in that context. Yes membership testing is the same with tuples and lists. So what?  It's still the wrong inefficient operation here because it tests each element where all you need is to compare the first one.